# How to start an application using QT and C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to start an application(.exe) using QT in windows environment. The below code giving an error while running my project.

```
Error:
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.
Signal name : SIGSEGV 
Signal meaning : Segmentation fault
```

When running:

```
QString path = "C:/Temp/myproject/AppTest.exe";

QProcess process;
process.execute(path)
```

Comment: Well that simply says that your AppTest.exe ("the inferior") crashed with a Segmantation fault. It seems everything else worked fine. If AppTest.exe runs fine in other situations than you most likely forgot some parameters on the command line.

Comment: Thanks,if I manually run apptest.exe, it works,

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a function for this and use relative paths. I think the command you need here is process->start(path, arguments) You will also need to set a QProcessEnviorment; Something like this:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess( parent );
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
process->setProcessEnvironment(env);
process->start(execPrgm, args);
```

I Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Wylie, it seems a permission while stepping through the code. Resolved the issue by providing enough permission.